# Android button click not fire

Tags: android, scrollview

First of all sorry for my english, This is my first question on StackOverflow, but I've learned a lot here .

Now I have a problem, which I couldn't solve. I have a framelayout with some elements. In android 4.x, Menu Panel's buttons onClick method doesn't fire. menupanel work to be in scroolview but in android 2.x buttons and layout work without problem as i want. I didn't find a problem.

Thanks for the help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Menu Panel starts here -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/menuPanel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_title_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#353535"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_title_1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aktifgorevlerim"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_5"
            android:background="@drawable/buton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="AYARLAR_Click"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="@string/item_1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </Button>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/aktifgorevlerim"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tamamlanmisgorevlerim"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_2"
            android:background="@drawable/buton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="GOREVLERIM_Click"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="@string/item_2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tamamlanmisgorevlerim"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="#b5b5b5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hakkinda"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
            android:background="@drawable/buton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="HAKKINDA_Click"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="HAKKINDA"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cikisyap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buton2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="CIKISYAP_Click"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="@string/item_4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- menuPanel ends here -->


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolpanel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_bg" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/header_vertical_divider_1"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuViewButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/engraved_bg" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/menuViewButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titlebar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Talep Detay Formu"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Textgorevbaslik"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Görev Başlığı"
                android:textSize="10pt" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Textgorevaciklama"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Açıklama"
                android:lines="6"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textSize="10pt" >
            </EditText>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Checkgrupgorevi"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="CHECKBOX_click"
                android:text="Grup Görevi mi ?" >
            </CheckBox>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnergorevkisilistesi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnergorevprojelistesi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnergorevdurumlistesi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Checkgorulmegorevi"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Sadece Yönetici ve Uzman Görebilsin ?" >
            </CheckBox>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnergorevonceliksirasi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btngorevekle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                android:height="35dp"
                android:onClick="GOREVEKLE"
                android:text="EKLE"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:width="100dp" />

            <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:height="100dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

onClick method

```
public void GOREVLERIM_Click(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(GorevEkleActivity.this, GorevActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Add your click method code.

Comment: yes add the onClick method. If there is no method you found the problem :)

Comment: In your manifest.xml add <activity android:name=".GorevActivity"/>  between </activity> and </application>

Comment: I added it already. I think problem related to scrollview but I could not find the solution

Comment: Try removing the onClick and replace with clickable set to true.

Comment: Try removing the onClick and replace with clickable set to true.  Then in your Activity add.. `Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aktifgorevlerim);                                                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), "YourActivity".class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers. I found the solution. I put scrollview in a linearlayout. Problem was solved.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolpanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >
           .
           .
           .
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```